# Check date between Dates in Database

Tags: php, mysql

Problem is this:

I want to check, wether my date lies between all dates in my DB.
This is my code:

```
if ($result = $con->query("SELECT `r_id` FROM `reservation` WHERE $cid BETWEEN `r_start` AND `r_ende` ")) {

    $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    }

$a=0;

    if($r>$a)
    {
        $message = "Your Startdate lies in an already booked span.";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        echo "<script>window.location='reservation.php';</script>";
    }
```

My DB looks like this

```
r_id    r_start     r_ende
   9    0004-01-24  0004-06-02
   8    0004-01-23  0004-06-02
```

`$cid` is my start date, which works and is correct.

It should get the `r_id` of the row where it lies between the timespan.
As the ID counts up it is always above 0, so if `$r` matches, it is above 0 and shows the error.
So if I my `$cid` is like `0004-01-25`, it should get the message, because `$r` is 9 or 8? But it doesn't..
As I `print_r($result);` I get `mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0`. For `print ($r);` nothing appears.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What if someone books the slot *while* your running this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM reservation where '".$cid."' between r_start and r_ende";
if ($result = $con->query($sql)) {
    $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
$a = 0;
if($r > $a)
{
    $message = "Your Startdate lies in an already booked span.";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location='reservation.php';</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since @ChandraKumar is not going to say what your error is I will.

By not enclosing your date in quotes MySQL is treating it as a mathematical formula.

`0004-01-24 = 4 - 1 - 24 = -21`

You need to enclose your date in quotes at which point MySQL will see it's a string, and since your checking against a date column, it will interpret it as a date.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful!

Answer (score -2):

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM reservation where '.$cid.' between r_start and r_ende";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
     $result ->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     $rows = $result ->rowCount();

   if($rows > 0)
    {
        $message = "Your Startdate lies in an already booked span.";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        echo "<script>window.location='reservation.php';</script>";
    }
```

Comment: If you're going to answer questions, tell the person what the solution was... and why!